# How to clear session when user is logged in but later deleted from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

When a user is authenticated to a web application, a token in session will be stored.
If the admin deletes the user in the back end when the user is still online. how to clear the user's session?

Comment: How is the admin deleting the user in the back end? Straight in the database?

Comment: You would need to check the database to see if the user account exists on the server.

Comment: How to call Session.Abandon for that particular user?

Comment: Admin may delete the user directly from the database or from a different application. (just sets the IsActive flag of the user to false in the database table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** you can't do this easily. Let the session expire, and the user won't be able to subsequently login.

**Long answer:** if this functionality is really important to you, then you will have to check the database with each request to ensure that the user hasn't been deleted since they logged in. This somewhat defeats the purpose of storing user information in session, although the call to the database can be a simple boolean check (i.e. "is the user still valid/active").

**Can't I just remove the user's session?** It doesn't appear to be possible to locate/manipulate a specific session even if you have the session ID in hand. Keys and storage are managed internally by implementations of `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` (`InProcSessionStateStore`, `OutOfProcSessionStateStore`, `SqlSessionStateStore`) and aren't intended to be manipulated by developers.

Answer (score 0):

By logging out the user before delete?

Answer (score 0):

Based on session Timeout and SlidingExpiration property. (thanks for @chethan). after session time out, user forced to login again 
from MSDN [SlidingExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx)

> Sliding expiration resets the expiration time for a valid
>   authentication cookie if a request is made and more than half of the
>   timeout interval has elapsed. If the cookie expires, the user must
>   re-authenticate. Setting the SlidingExpiration property to false can
>   improve the security of an application by limiting the time for which
>   an authentication cookie is valid, based on the configured timeout
>   value.

```
system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="x minutes"/> 
    ...
</system.web>
```

or else you can use AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore Method[AuthorizeCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore.aspx)

[Forms Authentication Guidelines](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ASP.NET_2.0_Security_Guidelines_-_Forms_Authentication)

Comment: The session doesn't expire if the user is active (sliding expiration set to true).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to clear the session or just prevent future access to authorised pages?

If you re-authenticate or check authorisation on each http server request then the user will effectively be logged out.

Comment: I just need to clear the session of the user. Any way since i check existence of session token on each request, the user will be redirected to login page once the session is cleared.